# printing a 2D array inside a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have made the following program in c++. I just want to print an array elements. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
#define n 5

double dist[n][n];

void read_distances()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ;j <  n; j++)
    {
        cout<<dist[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
 }

}

main()
{
    double dist[n][n] =
    {
        {0, 20,  30,   10,   11},
        {15,  0, 16,  4,   2},
        {3,  5,   0, 2,   4},
        {19,  6,    18,   0, 3},
        {16,  4,    7,   16,   0}
    };

read_distances();
}
```

I just wanted to print the dist[][] array inside the read_distances() function. But here I am getting all the values 0 as output. what's the reason of this?

Comment: `double dist` in main isn't the same as the one used in your print function.

Comment: because u re declare dist in your main

Comment: In main you are re-declaring dist.

Comment: why they are different? @πάντα ῥε

Comment: @user6663837 What makes you think they are the same?

Comment: You must master simpler exercises first, like printing an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you declared the `dist` array in `main()`, and you  initialized its contents, but the function `read_distances`() prints the values of a global array called `dist`. It happens to have the same name as the `dist` array in `main()`'s scope, but is a completely different array, and it is never initialized.

EDIT: you asked how to make it work. The easiest way is to pass it as a parameter. After removing the global declaration:

```
void read_distances(double dist[n][n])
{
    // ...
}
```

and then in your `main():`

```
read_distances(dist);
```

(technically, the parameter to `read_distances()` is actually `double (*)[n]`, but that's going to be a topic for another day and I didn't want to make this too confusing).

Comment: what will i need to do to print the dist arry of main functin inside read_distances()? @Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
#define n 5

void read_distances(double dist[n][n])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ;j <  n; j++)
    {
        cout<<dist[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
 }

}

int main()
{
    double dist[n][n] =
    {
        {0, 20,  30,   10,   11},
        {15,  0, 16,  4,   2},
        {3,  5,   0, 2,   4},
        {19,  6,    18,   0, 3},
        {16,  4,    7,   16,   0}
    };
    read_distances(dist);
}
```

Your code doesn't work because you overshadowed the global version of `dist` with the local one you created at main. So you either not use a global one, like I do here, and pass the one you create at `main()` to your printing function; or you fill that array without creating a new array in `main()`.